# Fastlane: "Could not find release for version code to update changelog"

Tags: flutter, fastlane

I'm trying to build and release an Android build to PlayStore using Fastlane, but when I run the lane the output is:

`Could not find release for version code '6' to update changelog`

My Fastfile:

```rb
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  lane :release do
    gradle(
      task: "bundle",
      build_type: "Release",
    )

    upload_to_play_store(
      track: "internal",
      skip_upload_changelogs: true,
      skip_upload_apk: true,
      version_name: "2.0.0",
      version_code: 6,
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For those that are also using Flutter and facing the same issue, specify your `apk` or `app bundle` file path.

In my case, setting: `aab: "../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab"` fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

FASTLANE: To improve the answer given above

```
 upload_to_play_store(
      track:'beta',
      version_code:4,
      version_name:'3.0.1',
      aab: "path-to-your-project/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab",
    
    )
```

If you use macbook and vs code like me You can copy path to your project by right-clicking on your aab file and copying path.